# Bootstrap - messed up @media and overflow issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

https://jsfiddle.net/537wen91/

I am using Bootstrap, and in the example, if you make html view wide, scrollbars disappear, when the view is narrow scrollbars show up. That is what I want. The problem starts when I am in the "narrow view": scroll down to the gray box, now expand html view, see how scrollbars are gone (good), but I also lost my text at the top (not good). Why is my text at the top gone?

**Edited to clarify**

This way it works: On page load - don't scroll anywhere and stretch the screen so that you see all colored columns on one row. You see some text at top, columns at the bottom, no scrollbar. This is how it should be.

This way it doesn't: Refresh page. Scroll down to the pink column. Now stretch it so that all colored columns appear on one row. See that my text at the top is gone? Why?

If this is still not clear, I would have to make a screen recording...

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
             <h2>title</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <h2>title</h2>

            <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus et ultrices neque, vel vestibulum turpis. In ex nunc, vulputate at quam vitae, ultrices vestibulum velit. Phasellus lorem orci, maximus vitae tristique a, sollicitudin sed mauris. Donec ipsum nibh, pulvinar quis nulla at, cursus congue odio. Cras accumsan sem erat, volutpat elementum ante accumsan sed.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <h2>title</h2>

            <p>bbb</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
             <h2>title</h2>

            <p>bbb</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <h2>title</h2>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="see" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #FFC;">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #CCC;">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #CCC;">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #FC9;">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #CCF;">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #CCF;">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <p>Place sticky footer content here.</p>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    /*position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;*/
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#see > div {
    height: 1200px;
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    min-height: inherit;
}
nav {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #666;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    body {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    #see > div {
        height: 500px;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).bind('resize load', function () {
    if ($(this).width() <= 992) {
        $('nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
    } else {
        $('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
    }
});
```

Comment: using FF36 here, your fiddle works fine!

Comment: I don't see any disappearing text. Can you be more specific? What element disappears?

Comment: See my clarification at the top.

Comment: The problem seems to be that for `#see > div` the width is updated, but not the height. Leaving it at 1200px and "hiding" your content outside of the viewport

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above, the issue is that `#see div` changes width but not height, and as the page was scrolled, the scrolling *remains*, leaving the text out of the viewport. Something like this (excuse my poor MSPaint skills):

[image]

One possible solution for that would be to scroll to the top of the page right before that change is made, so the text is always visible. You can achieve that just by adding a line of code:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/537wen91/12/

---

One possible CSS-only solution would be to, if the text height is constant, for the `#see div` add a height of `calc(100% - HEIGHT_OF_TEXT)`. But I haven't tried this.

Comment: I updated the link. Before it was at the beginning of the function, not it is inside the `else` branch

Comment: That resolves the issue. I will use this JS solution if there is not better CSS solution. Is that a bug that is a result of some faulty CSS on my side? Or something with Bootstrap?

Comment: I'd say it's neither. It's not a bug and it's not caused by faulty CSS... It's complicated to explain in text, and I don't know about a CSS-only solution for this if I'm correct. Imagine your window is 500px high and your page is 1200px high with the text occupying the top 300px (widths don't matter). The body has an `overflow:auto`, so it displays the scroll bars and you scroll 400px leaving the text out. Now in your code, you are changing the body display to `overflow:hidden`. The scrollbars aren't there anymore, but the scrolling value stays the same (400px) leaving the text out

Comment: Let me try drawing a sketch, I think it's easier to explain that way

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

with

```
body { overflow: auto; }
```

More info on Overflow values: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Are you trying just to hide overflow from the "#see" div in widescreen viewports? If so, replace `body { overflow: hidden; }` with `#see { overflow: hidden; }`

If not, can you explain further what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried that - not working. Did it work for you? I want on wide screens to have no scrollbars. Also, #see columns - the colored ones, will have a background images in them, and I want them to cover (span) the remainder of user's screen, thats why I made them 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to define what happens in different view sizes, using Bootstrap's grid layout: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
In your class, define grid sizes for these:
.col-xs-    .col-sm-    .col-md-    .col-lg-

Add hidden-xs to your class to hide in extra-small, or hidden-md in medium views, and so on (in the Fiddle below, if you make the width of the result window narrow enough, you will see this happen,

When you go to a smaller screen size, let's say you want to display two "title" elements instead of four, you would change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="hidden-xs col-md-2">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
   <div class="hidden-xs col-md-2">
</div>
```

This makes it so that on smaller screens, the only middle two elements will display as they will take up all 12 columns of the grid. Or you could make it so that on smaller views. Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1dtnd59s/1/

Basically the column options for different display sizes have to be tweaked, and if you're ok with hiding certain elements on small displays, that will make it easier.